# Efficiently count occurrences of each element from given ranges

Tags: algorithm

So i have some ranges like these:

```
2 4
1 9
4 5
4 7
```

For this the result should be

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 4
5 -> 3  
6 -> 2
7 -> 2
8 -> 1
9 -> 1
```

The naive approach will be to loop through all the ranges but that would be very inefficient and the worst case would take O(n * n)

What would be the efficient approach probably in O(n) or O(log(n))

Comment: No evidence for C++ relation, removed the tag, left a downvote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would prefer if somebody would answer this in C++ language. How come that is not relevant?

Comment: What exactly is the result, a map of items to counts? Do the ranges change frequently, i.e. do you need to be able to calculate the result on the fly?

Comment: No the ranges wont be changing. @MOehm I just have these ranges and i need the number of times a number is included in these pairs.

Comment: So you're actually asking someone here to write your code for you? Then hire some experienced developer, but don't expect getting it here for free. There are a lot of children that have to be fed, wives that need their needs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It aint like this question is a part of my job or something. I am just trying to learn stuffs and figure out efficient algorithms. And it aint like no one writes code as an answer. And why should I hire? I am a student myself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not an assignments. I am trying to practice for competitive programming. So i need to come up with an efficient algorithm as there are constraints involved.

Comment: @bayblade567 Learning from SO is a tough job, you'll be much better off studying books and tutorials, than asking here. If you're asking, research the site before, to be sure not asking a duplicate question that already achieved an answer solving your problems.

Comment: @bayblade567 Kindly elaborate please.

Comment: @bayblade567 ok understood, do u mind if i answer in C.

Comment: @Sumeet No of course not !

Comment: @bayblade567 ok I am writing  a very simple algorithm, it will definitely help you and u can very easily convert it into program.

Comment: @bayblade567 feel free for any queries.

Comment: @bayblade567 This is probably the best  in time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution, in O(n):

The rationale is to add a range [a, b] as a `+1` in a, and a `-1` after b. Then, after adding all the ranges, then compute the accumulated sums for that array and display it.

If you need to perform queries while adding the values, a better choice would be to use a Binary Indexed Tree, but your question doesn't seem to require this, so I left it out.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 1000
using namespace std;

int T[MAX];

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int min_index = 0x1f1f1f1f, max_index = 0;
    while(cin >> a >> b) {
        T[a] += 1;
        T[b+1] -= 1;
        min_index = min(min_index, a);
        max_index = max(max_index, b);
    }

    for(int i=min_index; i<=max_index; i++) {
        T[i] += T[i-1];   
        cout << i << " -> " << T[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Based on the "provocations" (in a good sense) by גלעד ברקן, you can also do this in O(n log n):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#define ull unsigned long long
#define miit map<ull, int>::iterator
using namespace std;

map<ull, int> T;

int main() {
    ull a, b;
    while(cin >> a >> b) {
        T[a] += 1;
        T[b+1] -= 1;
    }

    ull last;
    int count = 0;
    for(miit it = T.begin(); it != T.end(); it++) {
        if (count > 0)
            for(ull i=last; i<it->first; i++)
                cout << i << " " << count << endl;
        count += it->second;
        last = it->first;
    }
}
```

The advantage of this solution is being able to support ranges with much larger values (as long as the output isn't so large).

Comment: But what if the range goes up to 5 trillion? As in `[(2,4),(1555,1560),(4999999999991,5000000000000)]`

Comment: @גלעדברקן Then you can't even output the solution. Omega(n) is a clear lower bound.

Comment: @NiklasB. I most certainly *can* output the solution - the total count of elements in the example in my comment above is 3 + 6 + 10 = 19. But Juan's `T` array would oblige five trillion and one elements...

Comment: @גלעדברקן In that case, a variation of Paul's answer would do better in O(n log n). But I'm not certain if that's a requirement in OP's question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Oh I didn't realize zero counts are not part of the output. In fact OP's question does not say anything about that

Comment: @JuanLopes Yeah, I was also kind of teasing lol. Can you do it in a straight (n log n) without also depending on the number of disjoint counts already enumerated within the current examined range? (I couldn't see how to avoid that in my answer)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Included an alternate version that handles this case well (but is O(n log n))

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be pretty simple:

1. generate two lists with the indices of all starting and ending indices of the ranges and sort them.
2. Generate a counter for the number of ranges that cover the current index. Start at the first item that is at any range and iterate over all numbers to the last element that is in any range. Now if an index is either part of the list of starting-indices, we add 1 to the counter, if it's an element of the ending-indices, we substract 1 from the counter.

Implementation:

```
vector<int> count(int** ranges , int rangecount , int rangemin , int rangemax)
{
    vector<int> res;

    set<int> open, close;

    for(int** r = ranges ; r < ranges + sizeof(int*) * rangecount ; r++)
    {
        open.add((*r)[0]);
        close.add((*r)[1]);
    }

    int rc = 0;

    for(int i = rangemin ; i < rangemax ; i++)
    {
        if(open.count(i))
            ++rc;

        res.add(rc);

        if(close.count(i))
            --rc;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I would have had the `ranges` input be an array of structs, or had two separate inputs, instead of taking an array of pointers to start/end pairs.  Also, you don't handle the case where more than one range starts / ends at the same place.  `rc += open.count(i)`, I think would be better.  Also, if you told the `vector<int> res` how big it was going to get in the constructor, you could avoid inefficient copying as it grows.

Comment: Nice idea to use a `set<int>`, though.  That's probably significantly faster than sorting.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, not exactly the perfect solution

Comment: You can dual-purpose `res` to hold the `open` or `close` set.   `for (r in ranges) res[r.start]++;`  Still use a set (or vector) to hold the other set of values.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer still counts from "the first item that is at any range and iterate[s] over all numbers to the last element that is in any range." But what is we could aggregate overlapping counts? For example, if we have three (or say a very large number of) overlapping ranges `[(2,6),[1,6],[2,8]` the section `(2,6)` could be dependent only on *the number of ranges*, if we were to label the overlaps with their counts `[(1),3(2,6),(7,8)]`).

Using binary search (once for the start and a second time for the end of each interval), we could split the intervals and aggregate the counts in `O(n * log m * l)` time, where `n` is our number of given ranges and `m` is the number of resulting groups in the total range and `l` varies as the number of disjoint updates required for a particular overlap (the number of groups already within that range). Notice that at any time, we simply have a sorted list grouped as intervals with labeled count.

```
2 4
1 9
4 5
4 7

=>

(2,4)
(1),2(2,4),(5,9)
(1),2(2,3),3(4),2(5),(6,9)
(1),2(2,3),4(4),3(5),2(6,7),(8,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the output to be an array, where the value of each element is the number of input ranges that include it?

Yeah, the obvious solution would be to increment every element in the range by 1, for each range.

I think you can get more efficient if you sort the input ranges by start (primary), end (secondary).  So for 32bit start and end, `start:end` can be a 64bit sort key.  Actually, just sorting by `start` is fine, we need to sort the `end`s differently anyway.

Then you can see how many ranges you enter for an element, and (with a pqueue of range-ends) see how many you already left.

```
# pseudo-code with possible bugs.
# TODO: peek or put-back the element from ranges / ends
 # that made the condition false.

pqueue ends;    // priority queue
int depth = 0;  // how many ranges contain this element
for i in output.len {
    while (r = ranges.next && r.start <= i) {
        ends.push(r.end);
        depth++;
    }
    while (ends.pop < i) {
        depth--;
    }
    output[i] = depth;
}
assert ends.empty();
```

Actually, we can just sort the starts and ends separately into two separate priority queues.  There's no need to build the pqueue on the fly.  (Sorting an array of integers is more efficient than sorting an array of structs by one struct member, because you don't have to copy around as much data.)